# Spring Request method 'POST' not supported with th:field in select

Tags: spring, post, select, http-status-code-405

I have strange problem with post method from form to method in controller.
Every mapping is ok but when i put th:field in 'select' I receive an error 405.
I tried remove this (th:field=*{code}) and then it's working but i dont have value of this.

So, in my controller in GET method i put to the model list of Code objects and new Position of object (for form)
Then in form html in "select" i display every single Code object.
In short, i would like to post data from select to the post method in my controller

Thats my code in controller:

```
   @GetMapping("/add-shop-position")
public ModelAndView addShopPositionForm(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/addShopPosition");
    List<Code> codes = codeService.getAllCodes();
    modelAndView.addObject("codes", codes);
    modelAndView.addObject("position", new Position());
    return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/add-shop-position")
public ModelAndView addShopPositionSubmit(@ModelAttribute Position position){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("admin/addShopPosition");
    if(positionService.addPosition(position)){
        //I will do something here in future
    }else{
        //I will do something here in future
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

And of course my controller has RequestMapping:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController {}
```

And thats my form, html view in Thymeleaf:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/add-shop-position}" th:object="${position}" method="POST"
      style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{title}" th:placeholder="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{description}" th:placeholder="Description">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{code}">
            <option th:each="code : ${codes}"
                    th:value="${code}"
                    th:text="${code.getCode()}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: try changing `th:field="*{code}"` to `name="code"` and check if you receive it's value inside your `spring` controller

Comment: Nope ;( the same result

Comment: I still dont know solution  but if i put in th:value ${code.id} then its working. For me this solution is enough but i would be happy when i could put whole object in th:value